# how to add angular files on yeoman generator ionic

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, ionic-framework

I'm using generator-ionic from [link](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic), and It made well, but I want to know how to add angular controllers or directives files.

It's not like app when I made with 'yo angular'
there is no views folder and files neither.
'yo angular:directive myDirective' not work.

do I have to make all files and folders by myself?

Comment: Yes, because generator is not an official generator please post this question to repo page .

Comment: do you mean repo page for ionic?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Angular Generator works fine with a project created by `yo ionic`. You are correct that the folder structure is different, but that may not a problem for you. You could always start with a completely blank ionic template, and then start adding the pieces you need. Your app.js and index.html files will be where the Angular Generator expects them to be.

Comment: it's been long time tho, thanks for your answer. what's good for mobile-angular development environment these day? still yeoman-ionic generator is most one?

Comment: It seems to work just fine, and it's what some of my colleagues are using today. I'm just starting to work with it. My primary complaint, if you will, is that it still uses the `ionic start` command behind the scenes. I'm not a fan of the Angular code that generates, and was hoping for a generator that would use patterns closer to those in [John Papa's Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). Every time I start a new Ionic project, I need to go in a rework the JavaScript files to align with those patterns.